# Change script from blur to click

Tags: jquery

When I click on a div it focuses and I change the content, once i'm done changing and want to save, I click anywhere other than the focused div the div becomes unfocused and saves using the following jquery.

```html
editables.on('blur',function(){
        var current_element = $(this);

        var data = {
            page_id : current_element.data("page-id"),
            field_name: current_element.data("field-name"),
            data: current_element.html()
        };
});
```

I want to change the function to a click but I can only get it to work when I click outside the focused div and click it again, I want it to save it with a dedicated save button. here's what I have tried so far

```html
editables.on('click',function(){
        var current_element = $(this);

        var data = {
            page_id : current_element.data("page-id"),
            field_name: current_element.data("field-name"),
            data: current_element.html()
        };
});
```

Thanks

Comment: show the relevant html. Also where/what is the button that you will click to trigger the save ?

Comment: Hi the button is just a simple <a href="#"></a> with the id="button1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind click event on `button` rather than `editables`:

```
button.on('click', function () {
    editables.each(function() {
        var data = {
            page_id: $(this).data("page-id"),
            field_name: $(this).data("field-name"),
            data: $(this).html()
        };
    });
});
```

Where `button` is something like `$('#button')` in your case.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks. I'll mark it as answered once it let's me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom event and call it when clicking on the button..

```
editables.on('save-editable',function(){
        var current_element = $(this);

        var data = {
            page_id : current_element.data("page-id"),
            field_name: current_element.data("field-name"),
            data: current_element.html()
        };
});

$('#button1').click(function(){
   editables.trigger('save-editable');
});
```